# Vehicle Ownership/Registry on the Blockchain

Tags: contract-development

I am currently trying my hand at a basic PoC in the form of vehicle ownership on the Bockchain. I am familiar with Ethereum but not very good at coding.

Basically, the idea is that there will be a currency created on the blockchain with an initial supply and a small amount of inflation to deal with new vehicles after every vehicle has been registered. As of now, There will have to be a trusted party involved in the form of a government service and this trusted party will be responsible for registering each vehicle. Each single unit of currency will represent a vehicle in the real world and thus will have a unique identifier. Once a vehicle has been registered with the trusted party, it can be freely transferred on the blockchain.

Ideally, I would code a smart contract which would act as a intermediary for this transaction. For example, if x amount of Ether is received, send y vehicle ownership deed. However, I am unsure where to even begin. I have reasonable skills in coding in Java.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, as would any help or resources.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [token example](https://www.ethereum.org/token) from the Ethereum website. It's not exactly what you want, but it wouldn't be too hard to modify it for your purpose